# How to log Realtime PSQL errors

Tags: postgresql, psql

A while back i accidentally triggered realtime error messages in my PSQL console.

Basically, what this did was it would print the error messages from my querying services to the terminal as soon as the query failed.

For example: a user enters an invalid userId (a malformed uuid4) > the service would try and `SELECT * from users where userId = %s;` > (since the userId(%s) is malformed) the PSQL console would display an error like "%x : Not a valid uuid"

Can someone point out how i can re-achieve this pleasant mistake.

Comment: Define PSQL console? Are you talking about the command line program `psql` or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Very likely it was the same console where you started the PostgreSQL server, and you had `logging_collector = off`. Then PostgreSQL writes the log to standard error on the console.